# bash function implement python command

Tags: bash, functions

I have this

```
python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; \
    print ul.quote('sample hihi ')"
```

How can I wrap it into a bash function, so I can call it like a function like so:

```
urlencode('sample hihi ')
```

Thanks

Comment: This question should asked on stackoverflow, the possibility to receive an answer is higher then here.

Comment: @AtomiX84 shell scripting is perfectly on topic here. Please don't recommend moving on topic questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the function arguments into your Python code as regular shell arguments, which can be accessed there through the `sys.argv` array. In the Bash function, its call arguments can be accessed e.g. through `"$*"`, which returns all arguments as a single, space separated string argument (as if it were quoted as a whole, not separate tokens).

Here's an example that follows your original code:

```bsh
urlquote() { python -c 'import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.quote(sys.argv[1])' "$*" ;}
```

However, as Python 2 support will end soon, here's the better Python 3 equivalent:

```bsh
urlquote() { python3 -c 'import sys, urllib.parse as ul; print(ul.quote(sys.argv[1]))' "$*" ;}
```

The invocation is the same for both, type the function name followed by the string you want to encode as argument. Don't forget to quote it appropriately:

```bsh
$ urlquote "roses are red, violets are blue..."
roses%20are%20red%2C%20violets%20are%20blue...
```

---

**Note:** Don't ever directly inject shell arguments into your Python code string, like `python -c "print('$x')"`, as this could lead to easily exploitable security risks if you ever plan to run your function on untrusted input, allowing people to run arbitrary commands!

Have a look at this shell example, where I craft the argument in the variable `x` in a way to run the system command `uname` (which is harmless and just prints "Linux", but you can do everything here):

```bsh
$ x="');import os;os.system('uname');('"

$ python3 -c "print('$x')"
Linux
```